# Difference between different ways of writing records to Cassandra using Flink

Tags: cassandra, apache-flink

I was going through lots of posts over `SO` and the official documentation of Flink but I couldn't get what I was looking for. I am looking for the difference between `RichSinkFunction`, `RichAsyncFunction`, `AsyncIO` and `CassandraSink` for writing records `faster/multithreaded` in the `Cassandra DB` using `Flink`.

My understanding is as follows:

1. **`RichSinkFunction`** - If implemented properly, then it will do the work for you. Since it opens and closes the connection once.
2. **`RichAsyncFunction`**- Implementation same as RichSinkFunction. It works in `Sync` mode originally. I can use `executorService` for multithreading purposes. Also, I read that if the capacity is passed thoughtfully, it can give you higher throughput.
3. **`AsyncIO`** - Doesn't work multithreaded by default. Also, according to one of the SO answers, we can use `executorService` same as `RichAsyncFunction` for creating separate threads which are not mentioned in the documentation.
4. **`CassandraSink`** - Provided by `Flink` with various properties. Will using `setMaxConcurrentReqeuests` give me faster results?

What would be the best to use among the mentioned classes for the purpose I am looking for via the Flink program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use `CassandraSink`, which uses DataStax's java-driver(https://github.com/datastax/java-driver) to access Cassandra. Flink uses `executeAsync` function to achieve better speed. As you mentioned, `setMaxConcurrentRequests` sets the max number of requests that can be sent from the same session.

`RichSinkFunction` is a fundamental function in Flink. We can implement our own Cassandra Sink with `RichSinkFunction`, but it requires work like initialising the client, creating threads, etc.

`RichAsyncFunction` is mainly for the `AsyncIO` operator. We still have to initialise the Cassandra client. Except that, we only have to focus on implementing the `asyncInvoke` function and failure handling.

`CassandraSink` implements `RichSinkFunction` with Cassandra client's async API. This is the easiest async API with the least code.

Comment: So is Cassandra's client Async API and Flink's Async API different?

Comment: Cassandra client's Async API simply return a `Future` object and we have to handle them with a thread pool, for example. `Async API from Flink` implements the thread pool internally. But overall, both of them can achieve the same goal.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the explanation :)